# Why isn't my games component rendering inside of another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, sass, slideshow

I've tried multiple ways or rewriting including not mapping through my array of games from redux

```
// jsx rendering a component that return a slide of games that are imported from another component
return (
<div className="dash-con">
  <h1 className="feature-game">Featured Games</h1>
  <button className="button-scroll but1">Prev</button>
  <div className="slideshow">
    {gameArray.map((slide, index) => {
      return (
        <Games key={slide.id} src={slide.background_image} alt="444" />
      );
    })}
  </div>
  <button className="button-scroll but2">Next</button>
  <div className="games-card card-4">
    <div className="inner-graph">
      <span className="bodark">Favorited Games</span>
    </div>
```